# T-SQL stored procedure to return all records when input parameter is 'ALL'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that has the parameter:

```
@desk VARCHAR(50)
```

I want to

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Desk
WHERE DeskName = @desk
```

and I also want to return all records when the value for `@desk = 'All'`.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: See [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just include this condition in your `WHERE` clause like so:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Desk
WHERE   DeskName = @desk
OR      @desk = 'All'
```

As Martin Smith comments below, the performance of this won't be optimal - if the table is small, then you may prefer this concise approach over a more performant option simply for the sake of clarity/maintainability of your T-SQL code, but do also take a look at the article he links to...

Comment: This will do a full scan even if `DeskName` is indexed and a specific `DeskName` is passed.

Comment: I agree with @MartinSmith - See his link in the comments to the question.  In this specific case, the shortest code is perhaps the worst case.  An `IF` block, with two queries, will actually yield *significantly* better performance for the `DeskName = @desk` scenarios...

Comment: @Dems - The shortest code would probably be `@desk IN (DeskName,'All')`.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Picky ;) But true. And yet, avoids the point I had indended ;)

Answer (score 2):

As @MartinSmith pointed out, the `field = @var or @var = 'ALL'` type of answer has a huge down-side...

When the stored procedure is compiled, it generates a single execution plan.  And that execution plan needs to be sufficient to handle all scenarios that the parameters can throw at it.

In this particular case you probably *(MartinSmith says definitely)* scan the whole table every time.  This is because such an execution plan is capable of fullfilling both possible requirements.

So effectively, you end up with a single `least-worst case` execution plan.

To get a different plan for each case (`@desk = 'ALL'` and `@desk != 'All'`) you need to have two queries.  This means that, unfortunately, longer simpler less elegant code is significantly better performing code...

```
IF (@desk = 'ALL')
  SELECT * FROM dbo.Desk
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM dbo.Desk WHERE deskName = @desk
```

The link posted by @MartinSmith, in his comment to the Question, goes into this in a whole lot more detail.  Depending on your level of SQL experience, it's highly recommended reading; it explains a ***lot*** about the behaviour of SQL Server.  But it is very in depth.

A more simplistic approach is simply; try it and see.

Create a table with a *realistic* data-set for your purposes, with appropriate constraints and indexes.  Then, create a stored proc for each possible answer, and test them.  Ideally using the profiler to see CPU Time, Actual Time, Reads, Writes, etc.

You may see that the difference is so small you can live with the "worst" answer and benefit from it being short (and so making it the "best" for you).

You may see one is shorter in Actual Time, but vastly higher in CPU Time.  If you have high concurrency, you may therefore decide to go with the lowest CPU Time.  Or, if you have low concurrency, higher CPU Time but lower Actual Time may be preferrable.

Programming is wonderful, so many considersations, trades and balances.  Even with a piece of SQL as simpel as this :)

Answer (score 0):

The best & easy approach:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Desk WHERE deskName = CASE WHEN @desk='All' THEN deskName ELSE @desk END
```

Comment: Define `best & easy`?  It's more long winded than DavidM's answer and has the same over-heads as mentioned by MartinSmith's comment.  It's different, but I certainly would not say it's the `fastest`, `simplest`, or `shortest`, so I'm at a loss as to how it is the `best`?

Comment: I have stated as best & easy approach as one line does all. That's why its best and easy. I think people will find it more easy.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM dbo.Desk WHERE deskName = @desk OR @desk = 'ALL'`?  That's now one line too.  Or `SELECT * FROM dbo.Desk WHERE @desk IN (DeskName, 'All')`?  I'm not sure the *one line* thought means anything.  All SQL can be one line if you want it to be.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking only the other way and your comment have led me to think out of the box. That's why I love StackOverflow. Thanks Dems for arguing.!! :)

Answer (score -1):

```
Declare @Desk varchar(50)

if @Desk = 'All' set @Desk = null

select * from dbo.desk where deskname = coalesce(@desk, deskname)
```